# Where can I find Blender 32 bit version?

Tags: windows

On the [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/) Download page it only says 64 bit installer. I have a Windows 7, 32 bit computer and OS.

Comment: You can find all versions here: http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/

Answer (score 4):

Here it is:

[Blender 2.78c Windows 32 bit Download](https://www.blender.org/download/Blender2.78/blender-2.78c-windows32.msi/) (clicking this link will start the download)

To find it in the future, click on the "macOS, GNU/Linux, and other versions" button to find alternate versions, including 32 bit versions.

[image]

Hope this helps.